# Is there a measure theory for proper classes?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, set-theory

This question is very naive, but I'm curious: Is it straightforward to extend measure theory to proper classes?

Of course when one tries to define measures on "large sets" problems of non-measurability arise (e.g. non-Lebesgue measurable sets, Ulam's theorem, etc.). But setting those aside (since they arise already for measures over sets), are there any special problems that dealing with proper classes would raise?

To be a little bit more precise (and I'm afraid I can't do any better at the moment), let $\Omega$ be a proper class. Is there anything wrong with saying that a measure is a real-valued function with the usual properties (countable additivity, etc.) on a collection of sub-classes of $\Omega$?

In other words, can the usual definition of a measure be extended straightforwardly to proper classes or are there problems lurking here?

If this isn't entirely straightforward and you know of any references, I would appreciate them.

Comment: Do you have any example in mind? Mmh, perhaps distributions on surreal numbers...

Comment: Axiom of choice is used here and there in measure theory, so maybe you now also need it for classes. Not sure though.

Comment: @StefanPerko I don't have a particular proper class in mind. If there is something to say about the surreals, though, I'd be quite happy to hear it.

Comment: A proper class is too big to be an element of anything, which I would have thought would make it difficult to construct a $\sigma$-algebra for your measure